# Connect to Database using oracle client and kerberos with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, database, oracle, kerberos

I have a python script which basically uses `x_Oracle` oracle client to connect to my database server and after connection I can run my SQL queries.

Now, as my db credentials have expired and I am forced to use kerberos auth which I have no idea about. Previously just doing the below code would work:

```
conn_str = u'username/password@dbx1.ct.com:1521/dbx1.ct.com'
    conn = cx_Oracle.connect(conn_str)
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute(
        "select DISTINCT ITEM_ID,  UOM,  from SMCFS93 where item = '" + item + "'")
    for row in c:
        print(row)
```

But now I need to use kinit to generate a ticket and I have a `C:\kerberos\krb5.conf` file and  a `C:\krb5cc_User` file which I have given path location in SQL developer and then I can connect to my db server.

The method works fine if one wants to connect to DB using SQL developer but I am not able to get how to make this work in Python.

I tried creating a subprocess to enter kinit everytime and generate a ticket and tried few answers on stackoverflow  but I can't connect to my db. Any  suggestions on how to connect db server using kerberos will be of great help.

Comment: Hi @Duck_dragon, have you resolve your problem? I am also having issues when connecting to Oracle with Kerberos.

Comment: @Errol yes I have.

Comment: How did you resolve your problem? I am having problems with my connections. Can you guide me?

Comment: @Errol I realized that the path of oracle clients was wrong . Correcting it helped me solved my issue

Comment: Thanks for the info. But it still does not solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use krbcontext & jaydebeapi python libraries to connect to oracle database

```
import jaydebeapi as jj
import jpype as j
import krbcontext
    
with krbcontext.krbContext(
        using_keytab=True,
        principal=$KERBEROS_Principal,
        keytab_file=$keytab,
        ccache_file='/tmp/krb5cc'
    ):
        # create instance of JVM
        args = '-Djava.class.path=%s' % config.jdbc_jar
        jvm_path = j.getDefaultJVMPath()
        j.startJVM(jvm_path, args)
    
        conn = None
        try:
            conn = jj.connect("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver",
                              "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//{}:{}/{}",
                              {'username': $username,
                              'password': $password,
                              'oracle.net.authentication_services': "(KERBEROS5)"},
                              jars="jdbc6.jar")
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
```

From my own [blog](http://randomwits.com/blog/python-oracle-kerberos)

Answer (score 0):

Connect to Oracle from Python using the following:

- The OCI version of Oracle's Instant Client
- Kerberos via the Windows keystore
- jaydebeapi and jpype Python libraries

Benefits:

- No need to manually enter username/password to generate a Kerberos
  ticket.
- Authenticate using credentials the active windows session's
  Windows keystore.
- No Kerberos key files to track and secure
- Other applications (SQL*Plus, SQL Developer, etc) can re-use the same
  Kerberos configuration
- The krbcontext Python library is entirely
  unnecessary. Thus, no need for Docker on a Windows machine.

Steps:

1. Get a krb5.conf for your Windows domain from your IT people (or create one)
2. Configure the Oracle Instant Client to use Kerberos authentication by creating an sqlnet.ora text file in the Instant Client's \network\admin subdirectory. File contents:

   ```
   SQLNET.KERBEROS5_CONF={Path to your Krb5.conf file}
   SQLNET.KERBEROS5_CONF_MIT=TRUE
   SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES=(KERBEROS5PRE)
   SQLNET.KERBEROS5_CC_NAME=OSMSFT:
   ```
3. Verify that the Instant Client is correctly configured for Kerberos. The following command will connect and authenticate to the server without prompting you for username and password. (Do not replace the "/" with your username and password.)

   `sqlplus.exe /@server:port/SID`
4. Make sure that the Oracle Instant Client root directory is in your environment path. Otherwise the jaydebeapi.connect command will throw the following error: `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no ocijdbc19 in java.library.path`
5. Connect in Python using JDBC

   ```
   args = "-Djava.class.path=" + {jdbc_jar_file_path}
   jpype.startJVM(args, convertStrings = False)

   connection_string = 'jdbc:oracle:oci:/@server:port:sid'
   jaydebeapi.connect(
     {jdbc_java_class_name}
   , connection_string
   , jars = {jdbc_jar_file_path}
   )
   ```

Comment: If you can connect with SQL*Plus, then you can connect with cx_Oracle (both use Oracle Call Interface library to connect to the DB), and there is no need to use JDBC.  The original poster was using cx_Oracle.

Comment: @ChristopherJones You are correct.  The following command successfully connected me to Oracle: `conn = cx_Oracle.connect(dsn="server:port/SID", encoding="UTF-8")`

Comment: @ChristopherJones, I can not connect with SQL*Plus but I can connect using SQL Developer. What do you think is the problem?

Comment: @Errol SQL Developer is probably using a different install of the Oracle client.  Try copying the config files in your SQL*Plus \network\admin folder to the corresponding folder under SQL Developer.  Alternatively, you can force SQL Developer to use the same client as SQL*Plus in Tools --> Preferences --> Database --> Advanced.  (The "bit"-ness of SQL developer and the client must match.)

Comment: Cannot get it working. I have the credential cache and my sqlDeveloper works fine. Can you share the details on how does sqlplus knows where my credential caches is located?

Comment: @ericDaWang I believe the answer to your question is that everything is configured in the `sqlnet.ora` lines in step 2 and the `krb5.conf` file in step 1.   The `krb5.conf` will be specific to your company.   I have forgotten some details because I do not currently for a company that uses Oracle databases.

Comment: @JSkarda I got it working. Thanks! The OSMSFT: service provides the key that's associated with my login, so I didn't need to specify the path.