# Python Oracle Connection using cx_Oracle and Kerberos Auth

Tags: python, oracle, kerberos, cx-oracle

Is there a way to use the oracle python driver package cx_Oracle and specify Kerberos authentication?

I've seen this done using oracle jdbc drivers, but not with cx_Oracle specifically. Below is my current connection code:

```
dsn = cx_Oracle.makedsn(host="some host", port="some port", service_name="some service")
con = cx_Oracle.connect("user", "password", dsn, threaded=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe these will help:

Similar setup?
[Connect to Database using oracle client and kerberos with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56644611/connect-to-database-using-oracle-client-and-kerberos-with-python)

CX-Oracle or Python OracleDB with External Auth:
https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/issues/61#issuecomment-320121457